# Implementing Trailing Closure Syntax In A View Modifier That Wraps Another View

Tags: swiftui

I have the following `View` extension that allows the use of a `.toolbar` if it is available, but allows the code to compile if it is not:

```
@available(iOS 14, *)
struct ToolbarAvailable14ViewModifier<V>: ViewModifier where V: View {
    var placement: ToolbarItemPlacement
    var item: (V) -> V

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: placement) { //Type '(V) -> V' cannot conform to 'View'
                    item
                }
            }
    }
}

@available(iOS 15, *)
struct ToolbarAvailable15ViewModifier<V>: ViewModifier where V: View {
    var placement: ToolbarItemPlacement
    var item: (V) -> V
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: placement) { //Type '(V) -> V' cannot conform to 'View'
                    item
                }
            }
    }
}

extension View {
    @ViewBuilder
    func toolbarIfAvailable<V>(placement: ToolbarItemPlacement, _ item: @escaping (V) -> V) -> some View where V: View {
        if #available(iOS 14, *) {
            self
                .modifier(ToolbarAvailable14ViewModifier(placement: placement, item: item))
        }
        if #available(iOS 15, *) {
            self
                .modifier(ToolbarAvailable15ViewModifier(placement: placement, item: item))
        }
        else {
            self
        }
    }
}
```

The above gets me to here:

```
        .toolbarIfAvailable(placement: .keyboard) { _ in
            Button("Click") {
                print("Click Pressed")
            }
        }
```

My code is giving me the following error on each of the `ViewModifiers`:

"Type '(V) -> V' cannot conform to 'View'" V is a generic that is defined as `V: View`. Two related questions: 1. How do I get rid of the errors marked in the code, and 2. how do I get rid of the need for the `_ in` in the call?

I have reviewed these questions:
[Add view as a parameter to a custom ViewModifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65401146/add-view-as-a-parameter-to-a-custom-viewmodifier), [How to use view modifiers only available for iOS 14+ with deployment target of iOS 13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63077410/how-to-use-view-modifiers-only-available-for-ios-14-with-deployment-target-of-i) & [Modify view from within a view modifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61707073/modify-view-from-within-a-view-modifier), but they don't quite get me there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of your `item` parameters is defined as `(V) -> V` -- this means a closure that takes `V` as a parameter and returns `V`. In fact, all you want is `() -> V` (a closure that takes *no* parameters and returns `V`). That gets you the trailing closure you want -- then, you can pass *just* the `V` to the view modifiers.

```
@available(iOS 14, *)
struct ToolbarAvailable14ViewModifier<V>: ViewModifier where V: View {
    var placement: ToolbarItemPlacement
    var item: V

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: placement) {
                    item
                }
            }
    }
}

@available(iOS 15, *)
struct ToolbarAvailable15ViewModifier<V>: ViewModifier where V: View {
    var placement: ToolbarItemPlacement
    var item: V
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: placement) {
                    item
                }
            }
    }
}

extension View {
    @ViewBuilder
    func toolbarIfAvailable<V>(placement: ToolbarItemPlacement, _ item: @escaping () -> V) -> some View where V: View {
        if #available(iOS 14, *) {
            self
                .modifier(ToolbarAvailable14ViewModifier(placement: placement, item: item()))
        }
        if #available(iOS 15, *) {
            self
                .modifier(ToolbarAvailable15ViewModifier(placement: placement, item: item()))
        }
        else {
            self
        }
    }
}
```

This also takes care of your `_ in` issue since the closure no longer takes an argument/parameter.

Comment: Thank you! I never thought of passing `item()` instead of `item`, and it makes sense that it fixes the second issue as well.